# OpenCV Mat CV_32SC1 matrix addition has wrong results

Tags: opencv, addition, mat

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int a[2] = {-1, 0};
  cv::Mat b(1, 2, CV_32SC1, a);
  cout<<"b    : "<<b<<endl;
  cout<<"b+b+1: "<<b+b+1<<endl;
  cout<<"b+b  : "<<b+b<<endl;
  cout<<"b+b-1: "<<b+b-1<<endl;
  cout<<"b+b-2: "<<b+b-2<<endl;
  cout<<"b+b-3: "<<b+b-3<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The above code has the following result. Only the result on the first and third rows are correct. Why? Also check the attached image.
Thanks in advance!

```
b    : [-1, 0]
b+b+1: [0, 1]    // expect [-1, 1]
b+b  : [-2, 0]
b+b-1: [-2, 0]   // expect [-3, -1]
b+b-2: [-3, -1]  // expect [-4, -2]
b+b-3: [-4, -2]  // expect [-5, -3]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ll7S.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce (I get the correct results) with OpenCV 4.6.0 on Windows, using MSVC. What version/os/compiler is this happening with?

Comment: @Jioujiujiu can you also try just b+1 ? And 1+b+b?

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for your reply. It was with OpenCV 4.7 on Mac M1. I cannot reproduce it with OpenCV 4.7 on Windows neither.

Comment: Interesting -- you might want to file a bug report on OpenCV's github.

Comment: @Micka sorry for the late reply. I got [0, 1] for b+1, which is correct; and [0, 1] for 1+b+b, which is wrong.